# Getting ListView drawables and applying it manually

Tags: android, listview, drawable

i am trying to apply the style that a list item has, when it is selected, to a View (In my case a TextView)

[Example](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/images/hello-listview.png)

here it would be the orange-painted style. I found that this look is defined by a Drawable Object. So i tried, so get the drawable and applied it to my view

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);     

tv.setText("Hello, Android");
tv.setBackgroundDrawable(new ListView(this).getSelector());
setContentView(tv);
```

but it doesn't work.
Does anybody have an idea how to do that?

---

Ok I figured out how to do that. I found out hat ListView uses the ColorStateList list_selector_background which is defined in android.R.drawable. Using ResourceBrowser I got to know that the fourth color is the selected drawable so i added the following to my code

```
StateListDrawable listDrawables= (StateListDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.list_selector_background);
listDrawables.selectDrawable(3);
Drawable highlightDrawable = listDrawables.getCurrent();
```

Now I can set my Background using higlightDrawable. I don't know if it is possible to access the drawable in xml I did not try it yet. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be a pain to do it by code.

You need to implement a [selector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html) and let android know which resource needs to be used when the view is pressed, enabled or focused.

Here is sample [example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html) on how to achieve the same.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I see how this can help to define the look that i want to achieve. But how han I refer to the mentioned color in ListView drawable?

Comment: did you check the example at the bottom of the second link, he changes the color of text in the button, so just set your backgrounddrawable to the selector.

Comment: I realized how to do that. The problem  is that i do not know wich resource the selector uses. How can i figure out the resource id?

Comment: You need to define which resource the selector uses.. for example in this case <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@color/testcolor1"/> it uses the resource called testcolor1

Comment: I got it know. Thanks for your help. I would vote up your answer if I would be already allowed to do that